# Clock Table Details in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode

When I press <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-r</kbd> to print the clock report I get something like the following:

```
Clock summary at [2014-11-05 Wed 13:33]

| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0:01* |
|--------------+--------|
| test         | 0:01   |
```

The problem is that I have many entries at the same level. Like:

```
     * test
     CLOCK: [2014-11-05 Wed 13:13]--[2014-11-05 Wed 13:13] =>  0:00
     CLOCK: [2014-11-05 Wed 13:08]--[2014-11-05 Wed 13:09] =>  0:01
     CLOCK: [2014-11-05 Wed 13:08]--[2014-11-05 Wed 13:08] =>  0:00
```

Org-mode only recognizes details in sub-trees like:

```
* Haha
  #+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope subtree :timestamp t
  Clock summary at [2014-11-05 Wed 13:44]

  | Timestamp            | Headline     | Time   |      |
  |----------------------+--------------+--------+------|
  |                      | *Total time* | *0:03* |      |
  |----------------------+--------------+--------+------|
  |                      | Haha         | 0:03   |      |
  | 2014-11-05 Wed 13:40 | \__ test     |        | 0:03 |
  #+END:
```

Is there a way to print all the details within the same level, that is, all the clock entries and the length of each period?

Comment: I'm afraid not - AFAIU the point of clock tables is aggregating these data.  What is your use case?  Why do you want this?  Maybe you are looking for a specialized, custom *exporter*?

Comment: Nothing big. Sometimes I have two time periods inside one headline, and I want to print the clocktable of that headline (inside the headline itself) showing both periods. Instead, org only shows the total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunatley there is no way to do so directly. The idea of clock table is to aggregate data.

But fear not, you have two ways to solve the dillema: (That I can think of? there may be others).

#### 1) Use step by day:

Insert the following into your report line:

```
:step day
```

e.g: **[edit, below not tested, see comment for working example]**

```
 #+BEGIN: clocktable :step day  :maxlevel 2 :scope subtree :timestamp t
```

Then time reports will be split by day. By week is also an option, (The default shows total, the weekly shows by/week data.

#### 2) If you want it more granular than by day, then one option eaybe column view with sub-tasks might be the cup of tea that you've been longing for.

e.g

```
* Make Pizza
** Buy groceries
** Speak with the italian neighbour 
** prepare base 
** put things on top
** bake
```

Then set an estimate on each sub-heading, clock in/out what you worked on. Then hover over * Make Pizzaa  and press <kbd>C-c-x-c</kbd> and you will see a column with info on individual tasks.

It will look something like so:
http://www.devalot.com/assets/articles/2008/07/project-planning/columns.jpg

What ever you do, never forget: Just stay calm and org-on.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work - you need to specify `:block` or equivalent.  `#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope subtree :step day :block thisyear :stepskip0` is more useful, producing a report a day, but only for those days where there is non-zero time.